# How to use Listener method in antlr4 to get the contents of parsers?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

As far as I am concerned, the Listener method of antlr4 seems can only directly get the informations of TerminalNodes --- specifically the Lexer Nodes.

However, now I am hoping to put out the information of Parser like this:

```
type : 
        primitiveType
    |   referencedType
    |   arrayType
    |   listType
    |   mapType
    |   'void'
    ;

primitiveType : 
        'byte'
    |   'short'
    |   'int'
    |   'long'
    |   'char'  
    |   'float'
    |   'double'
    |   'boolean'
    ;
referencedType : 
        'String'
    |   'CharSequence'
    |   selfdefineType
    ;
```

First of all, I want to figure out how to diirectly get the contents of `primitiveType` and put out the contents like `byte` or `short` without changing it to Lexer(TerminalNode). I've checked the code of `aidlParser.java`(aidl.g4 is my initial grammar file(

Second, I want to know that if there is a way to know what actually a parser matches. E.g I want to know which regulation(like `primitiveType` or `referencedType` ...) of `type` is used in matching a type in the grammar without having to visit each sub-node(actually the regulations in Lisenter method) of `type` and see which one contains something.

Here is the entire code of my .g4 file:

```
grammar aidl;
//parser

//file
file : packageDeclaration* importDeclaration* parcelableDeclaration? interfaceDeclaration? ;
//packageDeclaration
packageDeclaration :'package' packageName ';';

packageName :   Identifier 
    | 
                packageName '.' Identifier;


// importDeclaration
importDeclaration 
    : 'import'  importName   ';'   
    ;

importName : Identifier 
|     
             importName '.' Identifier; 


//parcelableDeclaration
parcelableDeclaration : 'parcelable'   parcelableName   ';'   ;

parcelableName : Identifier ; 


//interfaceDeclaration
interfaceDeclaration :  interfaceTag?  'interface'  interfaceName  '{'  methodsDeclaration+  '}' ; 

interfaceTag : 'oneway' ;

interfaceName : Identifier ;


// methodsDeclaration
methodsDeclaration :  methodTag? returnType  methodName  '(' parameters?  ')'  ';'  ;

methodName : Identifier ;

methodTag: 'oneway';

returnType : type ; 


// parameters
parameters
    :   parameter (',' parameter)*
    ;


parameter
    :   parameterTag?  parameterType parameterName ;

parameterType : type ;

parameterName : Identifier;

parameterTag : 'in' | 'out' | 'inout' ;


// type 

type : 
        primitiveType
    |   referencedType
    |   arrayType
    |   listType
    |   mapType
    |   'void'
    ;

primitiveType : 
        'byte'
    |   'short'
    |   'int'
    |   'long'
    |   'char'  
    |   'float'
    |   'double'
    |   'boolean'
    ;
referencedType : 
        'String'
    |   'CharSequence'
    |   selfdefineType
    ;
selfdefineType : Identifier;

arrayType : primitiveType  dims
        |   referencedType dims
         ;

listType : 'List' ('<' (primitiveType | referencedType) (',' (primitiveType | referencedType))* '>')?;

mapType : 'Map' ('<' (primitiveType | referencedType) (',' (primitiveType | referencedType))* '>')?;

dims
    :    '[' ']' ( '[' ']')*
    ;



//Lexer

// Identifier
Identifier
    :   JavaLetter JavaLetterOrDigit*
    ;

fragment
JavaLetter
    :   [a-zA-Z$_] // these are the "java letters" below 0x7F
    |   // covers all characters above 0x7F which are not a surrogate
        ~[\u0000-\u007F\uD800-\uDBFF]
        {Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(_input.LA(-1))}?
    |   // covers UTF-16 surrogate pairs encodings for U+10000 to U+10FFFF
        [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        {Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(Character.toCodePoint((char)_input.LA(-2), (char)_input.LA(-1)))}?
    ;

fragment
JavaLetterOrDigit
    :   [a-zA-Z0-9$_] // these are the "java letters or digits" below 0x7F
    |   // covers all characters above 0x7F which are not a surrogate
        ~[\u0000-\u007F\uD800-\uDBFF]
        {Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(_input.LA(-1))}?
    |   // covers UTF-16 surrogate pairs encodings for U+10000 to U+10FFFF
        [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        {Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(Character.toCodePoint((char)_input.LA(-2), (char)_input.LA(-1)))}?
    ;


WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
    ;
```

I would sincerely be grateful for your help in time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your parse run is over you will get a parse tree. You can walk that tree down to the nodes you are interested in (usually you use a parse tree listener for that and only override the enter/exit* methods that are relevant for your problem). In your `enterPrimitveType` method you get an `EnterPrimitiveTypeContext` parameter. Use its `getText` method to get the text it matched.

For your second question you would do exactly the same, just use the `enterType` method instead. The `EnterTypeContext` parameter has members for each alternative in your rule. Check which one is not null to see which actually matched.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a try!

Comment: Actually the ```toString``` method seems not working and just return a []. However, its ```getText()``` method works just like toString and  can be used by Parser Nodes as well

Comment: Yeah, that is most probably what Mike meant to say. I'll edit his answer to reflect this.